# MS Access One-to-Many Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a service type database. Customers can have many equipment types and many service calls.
I'm trying to make a query that selects the customers name, address, etc when certain parameters are met with relation to the equipment types.

A customer can have upto 5 different equipment types. Some only have 1, some have all 5.
My query is trying to find customers with equipment type 3 installed, but not equipment type 5. The equipment type 3 must also have a service date between to date fields on my search form.

I'm drawing a blank when it comes to writing this query. I was able to query the customers with equipment type 3 and specific service dates, but I can't seem to be able to ***eliminate*** the customers that also have equipment 5 installed, even if they also have equipment type 3 installed.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
tblCustomers.WCWF_ID, 
tblCustomers.CustBusiness, 
tblCustomers.CustLastName, 
tblCustomers.CustFirstName, 
tblCustomers.CustAddress, 
tblCustomers.CustCity, 
tblCustomers.CustST, 
tblCustomers.CustZip5, 
tblEquip.EquipResinDate, 
tblEquip.EquipType, 
tblCustomers.CustPostCard
FROM 
tblCustomers 
INNER JOIN 
tblEquip ON tblCustomers.WCWF_ID = tblEquip.WCWF_ID
WHERE 
(((tblEquip.EquipResinDate) Between [forms]![MailSearchSelect]![StartDate]   And [forms]![MailSearchSelect]![EndDate]) 
AND ((tblEquip.EquipType)=3 
AND (tblEquip.EquipType)<>5) 
AND ((tblCustomers.CustPostCard)=True));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are tying to use a single JOIN to filter in customers with equipment type 3 and filter out customers with equipment type 5 : you would need to split that logic into two distinct parts.

To pull out customers that have equipment type  3 installed, using a JOIN is fine (I just moved the related conditions from the WHERE clause to the JOIN, for more clarity). It would also have been possible to express this requirement as a WHERE EXISTS condition with a correlated subquery.

To exclude customers that have equipment type 5 installed, you can either :

- use a NOT EXISTS condition in the WHERE clause with a correlated subquery (I chose that option)
- or use a LEFT JOIN with WHERE ... IS NULL.

Query :

```
SELECT
    c.WCWF_ID, 
    c.CustBusiness, 
    c.CustLastName, 
    c.CustFirstName, 
    c.CustAddress, 
    c.CustCity, 
    c.CustST, 
    c.CustZip5, 
    e.EquipResinDate, 
    c.EquipType, 
    c.CustPostCard
FROM
    tblCustomers AS c
    INNER JOIN tblEquip AS e
        ON e.WCWF_ID = c.WCWF_ID
        AND e.EquipType = 3
        AND e.EquipResinDate 
            BETWEEN [forms]![MailSearchSelect]![StartDate] 
            AND [forms]![MailSearchSelect]![EndDate]) 
WHERE
    c.CustPostCard = True
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tblEquip AS e2
        WHERE 
            e2.WCWF_ID = c.WCWF_ID
            AND e2.EquipType = 5
    )
```

PS : it is also a good idea to give alias to the table names ; it makes the query more readable and may avoid subtle bugs caused by name clashes when the same table is referenced more than once in the query.

Comment: I get a MS Access Error: JOIN Expression Not Supported.

Comment: @Rick : I think I was missing the AS keyword in table aliases, can you please try again ?

Comment: Think I got it.  There was a typo in the SELECT statement.  I fixed it and it seems to be working!  Thanks GMB!

Comment: Seems to work without the AS, but it was missing the S in NOT EXISTS.  And c.EquipResinDate should have been e.EquipResinDate.